# How does this PostgreSQL request work? (Java CriteriaBuilder)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to understand how this works. I have the following **CriteriaBuilder** which works with custom **jsonb_function**:

```
          builder.equal(
                builder.function("jsonb_function",
                        Boolean.class,
                        builder.literal(pathArrayLiteral),
                        root.get(ATTRIBUTE_COMPOSITION),
                        builder.literal(simpleEntries)),
                Boolean.TRUE);
```

The **jsonb_function** is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_function(path TEXT, json JSONB, searchSeq TEXT)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
    return (json #> cast(path as text[])) @> cast(searchSeq as jsonb);
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

An example of the first function argument ***path TEXT*** - {"transitCurrencyAccount"}. The second one ***json JSONB*** is json from DB which root gets (?).
The third one ***searchSeq TEXT*** - {"accountType":"12","accountNumber":"718294019284103"}.

So I see there is a kind of comparison in this ****jsonb_function**** which returns if the json from DB contains the passed arguments values but I don't clearly understand how it works. What exactly these parameters **'#>'** and **'@>'** do in plpgsql?

After I manage to understand it, I'll need to write a similar function with the only difference. It should return true for the *"accountNumber"* for example in all following cases: "718294019284103", "718", "71829", "7182940" etc.

Comment: The JSON operators `#>` and `@>` are documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! For some reason I could not manage to find the explanation for these operators.

Answer (score 0):

1. jsonb ***@>*** jsonb → boolean

****"Does the first JSON value contain the second?"****

```
'{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb @> '{"b":2}'::jsonb → true
```

2. jsonb **#>** text[] → jsonb

**Extracts JSON sub-object at the specified path, where path elements can be either field keys or array indexes.**

```
'{"a": {"b": ["foo","bar"]}}'::json #> '{a,b,1}' → "bar"
```